# Scala: custom grammar/parser combinators

Tags: scala, parsing, grammar, matching, parser-combinators

I write a Scala program which reads a string from the user, and uses either a recursive descent parser or parser combinator to determine if the input string matches the below grammar (i.e., is made up of a’s and b’s), while building a parse tree along the way. And then output the generated tree if the match is successful.

Grammar:

```
S -> E$
E -> C E2
E2 -> E
E2 -> NIL
C -> 'a' | 'b'
```

I am fairly new to Scala so any reading will  be much appreciated, If you have any ideas please let me know how I can implement this, Thank you.

This is what I have currently

Code I already have:

```
class MPParser extends JavaTokenParsers{
def c[C] = (“a” | “b”) ^^ {case ch => C(ch)}
}

abstract class MatchTree
case class C(s:String) extends MatchTree
```

The output should look something like this:

```
scala> Microproject.main(Array("ababa"))
input : ababa
[1.6] parsed: S(E(C(a),E(C(b),E(C(a),E(C(b),E(C(a),NIL()))))))

 scala> Microproject.main(Array("ababac"))
 input : ababac
[1.6] failure: `b' expected but `c' found

ababac
^
```

Comment: I would recommend [fastparse](http://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/). It is fast, simple and intuitive library. There are some examples in the docs, and here's some of my [stuff](https://github.com/sake92/nand2tetris).

Comment: I just don't understand how to put in my own grammars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Production rule `def c[C] = ...` looks strange. You probably meant `def c: Parser[C] = ...` instead.

The following code will show you how to define production rules and build a custom parse tree using `scala-parser-combinators`:

```scala
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

case class S(e: E)

// E2 -> E | NIL
sealed abstract class E2
case class E(c: C, e2: E2) extends E2
case object NIL extends E2 { override def toString = "NIL()" }

case class C(aOrB: String)

class MPParser extends RegexParsers {
  // S -> E
  def s: Parser[S] = e ^^ { S(_) }
  // E -> C E2
  def e: Parser[E] = c ~ e2 ^^ { case c ~ e2 => E(c, e2) }
  // E2 -> E | NIL
  def e2: Parser[E2] = opt(e) ^^ { _.getOrElse(NIL) }
  // C -> 'a' | 'b'
  def c: Parser[C] = ("a" | "b") ^^ { C(_) }
}

object Microproject extends App {
  val parser = new MPParser
  for (arg <- args) {
    println("input : " + arg)
    println(parser.parseAll(parser.s, arg))
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Live on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/aokmKsulSOanSZyAev3J9g)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you sir, very much appreciated